# Find the integer representing the last sub-string of a string

Tags: python, strings

I came across a question at the Udacity Intro to Computer Science course:

> Define a procedure, `find_last`, that takes as input two strings, a search string and a target string, and returns the last position in the search string where the target string appears, or `-1` if there are no occurrences.
>
> Example: `find_last('aaaa', 'a')` returns `3`

I think there should be a much cleaner (shorter, fewer words) way of writing this function:

```python
def find_last(s, t):
    count = 0
    if s.find(t) >= 0:
        while s.find(t, count + 1) >= 0:
            count += 1
        return count
    else:
        return s.find(t)
```

Comment: consider leveraging the ability to traverse lists backward in python. if you are looking for the last, its always the first if you go backward, and then you can just convert the index to output by adding the negative index to the strings length. just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

Well the short answer would be `str.rfind()`.

```
>>> find_last = lambda s, t: s.rfind(t)
>>> find_last("aaaa", "a")
3
```

Though I'm not sure *how much* you're required to implement yourself. (Does the task allow usage of `.find()` at all?) Maybe it could be written like this:

```
def find_last(s, t):
    start = 0
    while True:
        if s.find(t, start) < 0:
            return start - 1
        start += 1
```

```
def find_last(s, t):
    for i in range(len(s)-len(t), -1, -1):
        if s[i:i+len(t)] == t:
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the logic can be simplified a bit:

```
def find_last(s, t):
    count = -1
    while s.find(t, count + 1) >= 0:
        count += 1
    return count
```

This is shorter, and one unnecessary operation is eliminated too. But as the other answer points out, it's questionable whether you're allowed to use `find` at all in the exercise.